# Webrick connection reset error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, webrick

I am struck with the following webrick error

```
[2015-04-16 11:36:30] ERROR Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer @ io_fillbuf - fd:39 
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails3/gems/webrick-1.3.1/lib/webrick/httpserver.rb:80:in `eof?'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails3/gems/webrick-1.3.1/lib/webrick/httpserver.rb:80:in `run'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails3/gems/webrick-1.3.1/lib/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

I searched for the solutions online but nothing helps.

I am using Rails 3.2.1 and ruby 2.1.5

I want to know why this error occur and how to avoid it.

Any help is kindly appreciated.

Comment: No, I don't even have heroku installed

Comment: Use thin gem instead of webrick.

Comment: I am working by cloning a repository they won't allow me to replace webrick

Comment: After installing thin, the error seems to be gone, but the app. is not loading in the browser. By default it listens in port 3000 and there is no firewall issues.